# FormData fails to send Javascript

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, form-data

I am trying to send a simple form to a website that expects it. I found this code on a youtube video and it worked for him. This is my first time working with FormData and i have no clue what could be wrong.

Screnshots:

network:
[image]

console:

[image]

```
const data = new FormData();
data.append("name", name);
data.append("email", mail);

const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
xhr.open("POST", "correcturlnothingwronghere",true);
xhr.send(data);
```

Comment: Network tab screenshot says `ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`, so there's definitely something wrong with the URL

Comment: My company gave me the URL i cannot change it or anything.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem some time back working on a project using jquery maybe it'll work for you if you changed this:

```
xhr.open("POST", "correcturlnothingwronghere",true);
```

to this:

```
xhr.open("POST", "correcturlnothingwronghere",false);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set proper http header before sending.

```
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
```

Comment: Added that but it did not change anything.